# How to enable e2fsck checks every 5th boot?

Tags: linux

I want the e2fsck check the filesystem  on 
every 5th boot.

Comment: Any file on the filesystem that is read by the tune2fs for this ?

Answer (score 5):

The command you're looking for is `tune2fs`, specifically `-c max-mount-counts`:

```
tune2fs -c 5 /dev/sdawhatever
```